# Checking triviality of a finitely presented group

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am trying to see if the group

$G = \langle\ a,b,c,d\  \mid\ a^3 = b^3=c^3=d^3=$

$\qquad =(ab)^4= (ab^{-1})^4= (bc)^4= (bc^{-1})^4= (cd)^4= (cd^{-1})^4= (da)^4= (da^{-1})^4\ \rangle$

is trivial or not. I have tried all methods and tools I could but have not succeeded.

Knuth -- Bendix in Magma does not finish:

```
F <a,b,c,d> := FreeGroup(4);

L3  := [ w^3 : w in [ a, b, c, d ] ];
L4  := [ w^4 : w in [ a*b, a*b^-1, b*c, b*c^-1, c*d, c*d^-1, d*a, d*a^-1 ] ];

G := quo< F | L3 cat L4 >;

GR := RWSGroup(G : MaxRelations := 500000, TidyInt:=1000 );
// Warning: Knuth Bendix only partly succeeded
```

Determining the index of a large subgroup is inconclusive:

```
H := sub < G | a, b, c, (c*d)^2 >; 
Index(G,H:CosetLimit:=100000000,Hard:=true);
// 0
```

GAP fails as well:

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup("a","b","c","d");;
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(F);
#I  Assigned the global variables [ a, b, c, d ]
gap> 
gap> L3  := List ( [ a, b, c, d ], w -> w^3 );;
gap> L4  := List ( [ a*b, a*b^-1, b*c, b*c^-1, c*d, c*d^-1, d*a, d*a^-1 ], w -> w^4 );;
gap> 
gap> R:=Concatenation(L3,L4);;
gap> G:=F/R;
<fp group on the generators [ a, b, c, d ]>
gap> 
gap> gg := GeneratorsOfGroup(G);; 
gap> 
gap> LoadPackage("kbmag");
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Loading  kbmag 1.5.4 (Knuth-Bendix on Monoids and Automatic Groups)
by Derek Holt (http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/D.F.Holt/).
Homepage: https://gap-packages.github.io/kbmag
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
gap> R := KBMAGRewritingSystem(G);;
gap> 
gap> H := Subgroup(G,gg{[1,2,3]});; # < a, b, c >
gap> HR := SubgroupOfKBMAGRewritingSystem(R,H);;
gap> A := AutomaticStructureOnCosets(R,HR); 
#Knuth-Bendix program failed or was inconclusive. Giving up.
false
```

Are there any other methods I could try?

Comment: Stupid remark. First I assume the abelianization is trivial, since otherwise the answer would trivially be no and I expect you did the computation. Then writing $z=a^3$, we have $G=1$ iff $G/\langle z\rangle=1$ (since $z$ is central and $G$ perfect). So $z=1$ can be added to the input.

Comment: (Not familiar with gap but it seems that $z=1$ is actually assumed. It's missing to the presentation of $G$: you say that plenty of elements are equal, but you mean they're all equal to 1.)

Comment: It seems that the group has a lot of index 8 subgroups, at least LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup(G,8) returns a fairly long list. (4449 elements)

Comment: Also many of the subgroups of low index have infinite abelianization. This is a very standard method of proving computationally that finitely presented groups are infinite.

Comment: @Matthias thanks. I did not realize there was a built in method for finding low index subgroups. Very convenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's nontrivial, indeed infinite.

> $G\neq 1$; moreover it is an amalgam (actually a double) over a subgroup of index $\ge 3$ (thus is infinite and contains nonabelian free subgroups).

Indeed, write $$H=H(t,u)=\langle t,u\mid t^3,u^3,(tu)^4,(t^{-1}u)^4\rangle.$$

Conversely, let us first show that $H\neq 1$ implies $G\neq 1$. Note that $H\neq 1$ means that $t,u$ have order 3. Define $$L=L(t,u,v)=\langle t,u,v\mid t^3,u^3,v^3,(tu)^4,(t^{-1}u)^4,(uv)^4,(uv^{-1})^4\rangle.$$

Then $L$ is the amalgam of $H(t,u)$ and $H(u,v)$ over the cyclic subgroup of order 3 $\langle u\rangle$ (which by the way has index $\ge 3$, since $H$ is perfect and nontrivial and hence of cardinal $\ge 60$).

Let $M$ be the subgroup of $L(t,u,v)$ generated by $t$ and $v$. Consider the double $D$ of $L=L(t,u,v)$ over $M$, that is, the amalgam $L\ast_M L$. Then it has the presentation

$$D=\langle t,u,v,t_2,u_2,v_2\mid t^3,u^3,v^3,(tu)^4,(t^{-1}u)^4,(uv)^4,(uv^{-1})^4,t_2^3,u_2^3,v_2^3,(t_2u_2)^4,(t_2^{-1}u_2)^4,(u_2v_2)^4,(u_2v_2^{-1})^4,t=t_2,v=v_2\rangle.$$
Eliminate $v_2(=v)$ and $t_2(=t)$ and write $w=u_2$. This yields
$$D=\langle t,u,v,w\mid t^3,u^3,v^3,(tu)^4,(t^{-1}u)^4,(uv)^4,(uv^{-1})^4,w^3,(tw)^4,(t^{-1}w)^4,(wv)^4,(wv^{-1})^4\rangle,$$
where we precisely recognize $G$. Hence $G\neq 1$.

Now let us check that $G$ is a nontrivial amalgam- actually double- (over subgroups of index $\ge 3$). Indeed, let me discuss. If $M$ has index $\ge 3$, it's OK. $M$ can't have index 2 because $L$ is perfect. If $M=1$ (sounds unlikely but I haven't checked), then $L=M$ itself was described as an amalgam, actually a double.

Finally, to check that $H\neq 1$, just observe that in the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_7$, $t=(123)(456)$ and $u=(234)(576)$ satisfies the given relators of $H$.

Comment: Note: I found the proof that $H\neq 1$ after Matthias Wendt's comment that there is a subgroup of index 8 (so that I knew I should find in $\mathfrak{S}_8$ a pair of elements of order 3 with the given relations; there is not much choice).

Comment: PS: actually $M\neq L$: consider the given explicit elements $t,u$ of $\mathfrak{S}_7$; map $(t,u,v)$ to $(t,u,t)$ (sorry for the double meaning of $u$. This maps $L$ to $\mathfrak{S}_7$ and maps $M$ to a cyclic subgroup of order 3. So $M$ has index $\ge 20$ in $L$ (actually larger, since $H$ has no nontrivial homomorphism into $\mathrm{Alt}_5$).

Comment: PPS: the amalgam argument is similar to the argument of nontriviality of Higman's group, which similarly has a "cyclic" presentation on 4 generators and only relators involving two consecutive generators.